# Speed of the program changing in Turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

When I'm trying to run the program, its speed is varying from time to time. Here's my code below:

```
import turtle


# Making the Window
screen=turtle.Screen()
screen.title('PingPong Game made by using Turtle')
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=800,height=600)
screen.tracer(0)


# Sprites

# Paddle A
paddle_a=turtle.Turtle()    # It make the sprite (paddle_a) an object of the turtle
paddle_a.speed(0)   # Its not the speed of the movement of the sprite, its the speed of the animation. Here its set to the maximum possible speed using '0'
paddle_a.shape('square')    # Sets the shape of the sprite
paddle_a.color('white')    # Sets the colour of the sprite
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_len=1,stretch_wid=5)    # Increases the length and width of the sprite (Can also be done vise-versa(length is the side length , width is the height))
paddle_a.penup()    # Normally when we use turtle, the sprites constantly leave line fro where they move. (.penup) removes the line and leaves the background only
paddle_a.goto(-350,0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b=turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape('square')
paddle_b.color('white')
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_len=1,stretch_wid=5)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350,0)

# Ball
ball=turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape('circle')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0,0)
ball.change_x=0
ball.change_y=0.7


# Sprite Functions

# Paddle A
def paddle_a_up():    # Moving the sprite (paddle_a) down
    y=paddle_a.ycor()    # Setting a var y to the Y cord of the sprite (paddle_a)
    y+=20    # Increasing the y value variable (Its not increasing the Y coord its just increasing the value of the var)
    paddle_a.sety(y)    # Setting the Y cord to the Y level
def paddle_a_down():
    y=paddle_a.ycor()
    y-=20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

# Paddle B
def paddle_b_up():    # Moving the sprite (paddle_a) down
    y=paddle_b.ycor()    # Setting a var y to the Y cord of the sprite (paddle_a)
    y+=20    # Increasing the y value variable (Its not increasing the Y coord its just increasing the value of the var)
    paddle_b.sety(y)    # Setting the Y cord to the Y level
def paddle_b_down():
    y=paddle_b.ycor()
    y-=20
    paddle_b.sety(y)


# Using the Keyboard
screen.listen()    # Searches for a key press
screen.onkeypress(paddle_a_up,'Up')    # Does the function in the first argument when the key in the second argument is pressed
screen.onkeypress(paddle_a_down,'Down')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_b_up,'w')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_b_down,'s')


# Game Loop
while True:
    screen.update()


    # Moving the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor()+ ball.change_x)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor()+ball.change_y)


    # Borders
    if ball.ycor()>=285:
        ball.change_y=-0.7
    if ball.ycor()<=-285:
        ball.change_y=0.7
```

Now the problem is that when my paddle stays still, it runs OK. But when I try to move my paddle around, the speed of the ball decreases. Also if I take my paddle out of the screen, it doesn't matter if I'm moving the paddle or not, the speed of the ball becomes approx 2 times fast.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I don't experience the delays you describe. My guess is it might be Python environment-related -- include in your question which Python platform you're using.  (E.g. is this Python turtle on the Replit site or standard Python on Windows?)

My suggestion code-wise is that in time-critical methods, do as little as possible. That may mean doing more setup work ahead. For example, below I (reshape and) set the heading of your paddles in the vertical dimension so you can simply use `forward()` and `backward()` to move them, rather than interrogate, calculate and then move. Similarly, when moving the ball, avoid calling methods like `xcor()` multiple times, and avoid calling `xcor()` and `ycor()` separately when you can get both at once via `position()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Sprite Functions

# Paddle A
def paddle_a_up():
    paddle_a.forward(20)

def paddle_a_down():
    paddle_a.backward(20)

# Paddle B
def paddle_b_up():
    paddle_b.forward(20)

def paddle_b_down():
    paddle_b.backward(20)

def move():
    x, y = ball.position()

    # Borders
    if not -285 < y < 285:
        ball.change_y = -ball.change_y

    # Move the ball
    ball.goto(x + ball.change_x, y + ball.change_y)

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move)

# Making the Window
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.title('PingPong Game made by using Turtle')
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(False)

# Sprites

# Paddle A
paddle_a = Turtle()
paddle_a.shape('square')
paddle_a.color('white')
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_len=5)  # Increases the length of the sprite
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.setheading(90)
paddle_a.setx(-350)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = paddle_a.clone()
paddle_b.setx(350)

# Ball
ball = Turtle()
ball.shape('circle')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()

ball.change_x = 0.5  # user defined properties
ball.change_y = 1

# Using the Keyboard
screen.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, 's')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, 'Down')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

I hope some of these changes help, but again, my guess it's the environment you're running under that's the issue.

(I reversed the keys that control your paddles as it didn't seem natural to me to control the right paddle with my left hand and vice-versa.)

Comment: Well thanks for the tips like forward or backward as im new to turtle